# convert c++ code into c#

Tags: c#, c++, interop, com-interop

This is code snippet from c++

```
struct 
    {
        short       m_nVersion;
        short       m_nMOT_Addr;
        q_address   m_oDistribution_Q;
        short       m_nOffset;
        char        m_cOperator;
        short       m_cLength;
        long        m_lOperand;
        char        m_cReq_Ack;
        char        m_cReq_SeqGap;
        char        m_cReq_AutoDereg;
    } oSbsReg;

    const short nMsgSize = 20;  //20 byte long structure when packed

    char sMessageBuffer[nMsgSize]; // I created stringbuilder in c#

    memset(&oSbsReg,0,sizeof(oSbsReg));
    memset(sMessageBuffer,0,sizeof(sMessageBuffer));

    oSbsReg.m_nVersion = 20;                        //Version
    oSbsReg.m_nMOT_Addr = (short) lMot;             //MOT in which to register with
    oSbsReg.m_oDistribution_Q.au.queue = m_oQueue.au.queue; //Current queue number
    oSbsReg.m_oDistribution_Q.au.group = m_oQueue.au.group; //Current group 
    //changed to 0 to resolve Oswego issue when moved to DMQ 5.0
    oSbsReg.m_nOffset = 0;                          //Start byte for telegram match
    oSbsReg.m_cOperator = PSEL_OPER_EQ;             //Exact match
    oSbsReg.m_cLength = 4;                          //Number of bytes in match
    oSbsReg.m_lOperand = lTelegramId;               //Telegram Id to match against
    oSbsReg.m_cReq_Ack = 1;                         //TRUE: Request an acknowledge of registration
    oSbsReg.m_cReq_SeqGap = 1;                      //TRUE: Request an acknowledge of a sequence gap
    oSbsReg.m_cReq_AutoDereg = 1;                   //TRUE: Request an auto deregistration on a connection loss

    //default compile option is 8 byte packing, didn't want to change it
    //manually pack bytes in structure to satisfy the SBS server's expectations
    memcpy(sMessageBuffer, &oSbsReg, 11);
    memcpy(sMessageBuffer+11, &(oSbsReg.m_cLength), 2);
    memcpy(sMessageBuffer+13, &(oSbsReg.m_lOperand), 7); //twenty bytes max!
```

I need to convert above code in c#,

i created above structure in c# and initialized too but now i want to put it in stringbuilder variable, same way above structure in put into char array. But as you can see they use memset and mem cpy functions.

How can i achieve the same thing in c# ?

How can i put above structure in stringbuilder variable c#, how i extract bytes from structure and put it in string builder variable ?

Comment: Which idiot gave me -2 rank, what wrong did i ask ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using `char`s for storing bytes in C# (`char` in C# is actually two bytes because it's unicode).
There's a datatype for this kind of data in .NET, it's called `byte`, which is more similar to C++'s `char`, because it also contains one byte.

If you replace `T` with the name of your struct type, you can convert an object to a byte array like this (btw you can make a quite useful generic method out of this):

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
byte[] rawData = new byte[size];

IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
Marshal.Copy(ptr, rawData, 0, size);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```